# Determine which promise is slowest in Promises.all

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have been using Promise.all in my app. 
For the purpose of improving app speed, how to determine which promise is the slowest?

```
const result = await Promise.all([
          this.props.fetchUser(),
          this.props.cacheResourcesAsync(),
          this.props.initAmplitude(),
          this.props.initAppVariables(),
        ]);
```

Comment: why not to add a then block to each promise and log the time taken, define a global start time and in the end, check each log?

Comment: check the 'network' of chrome console?

Comment: what if some are non-network async calls like file read?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a good idea. Please put that in your answer so that I can mark it as the answer. @binariedMe

Comment: @C.Lee have added the code. Refactor it to make it look good. :)

Comment: did you need the timings available in your code, or is the console fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a helper function for that:

```
async function time(p, name) {
    const start = Date.now();
    try {
        return await p;
    } finally {
        const end = Date.now();
        console.log(`${name} took ${end-start}ms`);
    }
}
```

Then write

```
const result = await Promise.all([
    time(this.props.fetchUser(), "user"),
    time(this.props.cacheResourcesAsync(), "cacheResources"),
    time(this.props.initAmplitude(), "amplitude"),
    time(this.props.initAppVariables(), "appVars"),
]);
```

Comment: you could also use `console.time(name)` and `console.timeEnd(name)` instead of your const's start and end :p

Comment: @JaromandaX But using console.time is a bit risky. If some other piece of code is also using console.time, code will fail

Comment: only if the string argument is the same as one you want to use, but good point

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this :

```
let startTime = new Date();
Promise.all([
  this.fetchUser().then(() => { 
    console.log('fetch user takes', new Date().getTime()-startTime.getTime());
    return arguments;}),
  this.fetchData().then(() => {
    console.log('fetchData takes', new Date().getTime()-startTime.getTime());
    return arguments;})
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems Bergi's solution is more reusable, but thumbs up to your solution, too!