# Log time taken to execute aync await function

Tags: javascript

How can I find how much time this function takes to execute?

```
export async function queryElasticSearch(userQuery, index) {
    if (_.isEmpty(userQuery)) {
        throw new Error('User query is empty or null');
    }
    try {
        const elasticSearchRequestBody = getElasticSearchRequestBody(index, userQuery);
        return await elasticSearchClient.search(elasticSearchRequestBody);
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

Comment: `catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }` is pointless. Just drop the entire `try` wrapper.

Comment: Have a  look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43861797/1048572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
export async function queryElasticSearch(userQuery, index) {
  const start = Date.now()
  try {
    if (_.isEmpty(userQuery)) throw new Error('User query is empty or null');
    const elasticSearchRequestBody = getElasticSearchRequestBody(index, userQuery);
    return await elasticSearchClient.search(elasticSearchRequestBody);
  } finally {
    console.log(Date.now() - start)
  }
}
```

Or alternatively, you can use **performance.now()** if you want precision in microseconds...

*Edit: added finally per Bergi suggestion.*

Comment: You should just use `finally` to take the end timestamp

Answer (score 0):

you can also implement this with `console.time` ie

```
    export async function queryElasticSearch(userQuery, index) {
  console.time('time');
  try {
    if (_.isEmpty(userQuery)) throw new Error('User query is empty or null');
    const elasticSearchRequestBody = getElasticSearchRequestBody(index, userQuery);
    return await elasticSearchClient.search(elasticSearchRequestBody);
  } finally {
    console.timeEnd('time')
  }
}
```